# запуск двух одинаковых контейнеров docker-compose на одном сервере

Tags: docker

Все привет, столкнулся с проблемой. Есть микросервис, его docker-compose:

```
version: "3.3"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: traefik

services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: test
    command: sh -c "uvicorn app.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 7778"
    restart: always
    links:
      - db_test
      - worker_test
      - beat_test
      - rabbitmq_test
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/code/app
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.subdomain=test"
      - "traefik.http.services.test.loadbalancer.server.port=7778"
      - "traefik.http.routers.test.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt"

    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db_test

  db_test:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db-test
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: docker
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
      POSTGRES_DB: test
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  worker_test:
    build: .
    container_name: merge_duplicates_worker-test
    restart: always
    command: ./app/worker.sh
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq_test

  beat_test:
    build: .
    container_name: beat-test
    command: ./app/beat.sh
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq_test

  rabbitmq_test:
    container_name: rabbitmq-test
    restart: always
    image: "rabbitmq:3.10.5"
```

Когда запускаю все нормально работает как нужно, теперь меняю порт для траефик, traefik.subdomain, названия контейнеров и т.д. и запускаю второй контейнер, он работает без ошибок, но проблема в том, что в новый контейнер в базу данных подтягиваются данные из первого контейнера его базы данных. Links никак не влияет на это, пробовал удалять, эффекта ноль.

Answer (score 1):

в переменных окружения не видел строки подключения к db (что-то вроде db-test:5432), значит она внесена где-то в конфигах приложения.
Варианты:

1. вынести этот параметр в переменные окружения и задать отдельно для каждого инстанса app
2. определить новую сеть и развернуть все контейнеры в ней

```
services:
  app:
    ...
    networks:
      - instance2
networks:
  instance2:
    external: true
```